# How to use a type from another module as a JSDoc return/param type

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, jsdoc, discord.js

I'm trying to use JSDoc to document some functions of a bot I'm making:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

/**
 * Returns and empty embed with the bot's default settings
 * @param u - The user that executed the command
 * @returns {Discord.RichEmbed}
 */
exports.getDefaultEmbed = function(u) {
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed();
    embed.setColor(0xFA632A);
    if (u) embed.setFooter(u.tag, u.displayAvatarURL);
    return embed;
};
```

As you can see, this function returns a RichEmbed object from the `discord.js` module, but WebStorm doesn't seem to like that.

[image: WebStorm doesn't seem to like that]

So, how do I use a type from another module in JSDoc?

Comment: what does the `RichEmbed()` declaration look like (the way it's exported, documented, etc.)?

Comment: Which branch are you using? Because in master RichEmbed does not exist anymore, it's only in stable. In master it's now MessageEmbed, while in stable MessageEmbed is used only for Received messages.

Comment: Related; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793858/how-do-i-use-jsdoc-type-inference-in-webstorm-on-a-module-with-a-dot-in-its-nam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of [WebstormProblem](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34348) any modules with a `.` dot/period in it's module name can cause problems.

A workaround that seems to work on my end is, Use ESMA6 and use backquotes to require the module.

### With regular quotes

[image: With regular quotes]

### With backquotes

[image: With back quotes]