# How do I use JSDoc type inference in WebStorm on a module with a dot in it's name? (Discord.js)

Tags: ecmascript-6, webstorm, node-modules, jetbrains-ide, discord.js

I'm trying to find a way to work with Discord.js TypeScript annotations using WebStorm's JSDoc type inference in a non-conflicting pattern.

Here's what "works"...

```js
import Discord from 'discord.js';

/**
 * @param {Client} client
 * @param {Collection.<Snowflake, Message>} msgs
 */
function handleRemoveMessages(client, msgs) {}
```

[image: Message and Snowflake are resolved just fine.]

The problem is with Client, multiple definitions exist.
[image: The problem is with Client, multiple definitions exist.]
While this works, I'd like to be able to namespace the imported types from the `discord.js` module into something like `Discord.Client` instead of `Client`, as I'd like to use other symbols named such.

So, for example... `Message` is referencing the correct type;
[image: Message is referencing the correct type]
And `Discord.Message` *appears* to be referencing the correct type (but I don't believe it is);
[image: Discord.Message appears to be referencing the correct type]
The two `Message` type references are not compatible, and throw a warning when one is supplied to represent the other.
[image: The two Message type references are not compatible]
It's also not possible to reference the type via a JSDoc module path...
[image: The module path can not be resolved]
[image: Variation on the module path can not be resolved]
I also tried `module:discord\.js`, `module:'discord\.js'` and also with double quotes, all with the same results.

I know that using a dot in a JSDoc path name is a bit of a hack, and that the Closure compiler used by JetBrains may not be 100% up on JSDoc compliance.

Is this just a bug in WebStorm or Closure or is there a way to correctly make this module type reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to [JSDoc 3 spec](http://usejsdoc.org/about-namepaths.html), you need to quote the names with 'unusual' chanracters, like `module:"discord.js"`. But it doesn't currently work as expected, please follow [WEB-34348](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34348) for updates

Comment: This is what I'm afraid of. I'm going to wait to see if anyone has a workaround, or if JetBrains responds. I'll follow WEB-34348 to see what happens. I'll likely accept this answer soon.